# Install4j update main program jar silently

Tags: java, install4j

I am trying to create an updater which updates main java program jar silently.
When I am trying to delete or replace jar after downloading it says "unable to delete file", looks its locked by executable.

My Launcher configurations are shown 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9hrh.png).
Please confirm if its feasible to achieve the same using install4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that an executable that uses this JAR file is still running. There should be a "Shut down calling launcher" action in the updater that is invoked before an update is applied.